# A bypass server php code to download file from another server

Tags: php, httpserver, download

My situation is illustrated in the figure below:

[image]

I have a **file X** on the **main server A** which I want to download from my **local computer B** and the file X is downloadable through HTTP. But, for some reason I am not allowed to download file from the **main server A**. However, I have an access to **another server C** which has PHP installed.
I now want to download the **file X** via the **server C** by calling some PHP script on **server C** from my **local computer B**.

Is it possible to write one **PHP script** to do the above?

**Any help in writing so** will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does server C have access to file X on server A?

Comment: @JimL Yes, it has and the file X is downloadable through HTTP from any computer except B.

Comment: Check the updated script with a password, otherwise it's unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of what you need but you can use the following script to act as proxy between 2 servers.

**PUT THIS FILE ON SERVER C**

**phpProxy.php**

```
<?php
$myPass = "Secr3t";
if( $myPass == $_GET['pass'] ){
    $remoteFile = $_GET['rf'];
    $filename = basename( $remoteFile );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    echo file_get_contents( $remoteFile );
}
```

---

**USE AS:**

```
phpProxy.php?rf=http://phs.googlecode.com/files/Download%20File%20Test.zip&pass=Secr3t
```

---

**NOTES:**
1 - I've added a `password` otherwise the script is very **unsafe**!
2 - If possible, use `https` to avoid [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: That's it exactly! Thanks a lot.